# TypeError 'Profile' object is not iterable

Tags: python, html, django

I keep getting this error, I can't seem to fix it. Each time a new user signs up, he/she can create a profile. I can create and edit a profile, but I can't view the profile. Maybe my code is wrong, but idk. I am fairly inexperienced.

```
TypeError at /profile/1/
'Profile' object is not iterable
```

Url:

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.profile, name='profile')
```

View:

```
@login_required
def profile(request, pk):
    prof = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/profile_detail.html', {'prof': prof})
```

Model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='prof')
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

HTML:

```
{% for pro in prof %}
    <a href="{% url 'profile_edit' pk=prof.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
    <h2>{{ user.username }}</h2>
    <p>{{ user.profile.bio }}</p>
    <p>{{ user.profile.location }}</p>
    <p>{{ user.profile.birth_date }}</p>
{% empty %}
    <a href="{% url 'profile_new' pk=prof.pk %}"><span class="gliphicon gliphicon-plus"></span></a>
{% endfor %}
```

If I am supplying too little information, please say so nicely, no nasty comments and down-votes please. Please help a noob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only passing a single object `prof` in the context to the template but are iterating over an iterable.

You need to replace `{% for pro in prof %}` with `{% if prof %}` in your template.

Comment: Thanks for giving me that answer, I mostly copied from code that is similar to this, so there where faults in the code from the beginning